# MongoDB Aggregate average of two fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to compute the utilisation percentage of my fleet of vehicles. The formula to do so is (time spent moving in seconds + time spent idling in seconds) / [(total seconds in a day) * 100, which is 864].

Here is my current aggregation pipeline that works for `time_moving`. How do I include `time_idling` in it? `time_moving` and `time_idling` are both available in the same schema.

```
{"$group": {
    "_id": {
        "customer": "$customer",
        "date": "$date"
    },
    "percentage": {
        "$avg": {"$divide": ["$time_moving", 864]}
    }
}}
```

Data set (two customers, c1 & c2 having a fleet of two vehicles each, v1 and v2, on two days, d1 and d2):

```
customer    date        time_moving     time_idling vehicle
c1          d1           8200           400         v1
c1          d1          28200             0         v2
c2          d1           6400           800         v1
c2          d1          19900           100         v2
c1          d2          65500           500         v1
c1          d2           9800           100         v2
c2          d2          55000           200         v1
c2          d2          13000           200         v2
```

Sample Output (or differenty structured output with same data points):

```
{ "_id" : { "customer" : "c1", "date" : "d1" }, "percentage" : 42.59... }
{ "_id" : { "customer" : "c1", "date" : "d2" }, "percentage" : 87.84... }
{ "_id" : { "customer" : "c2", "date" : "d1" }, "percentage" : 31.48... }
{ "_id" : { "customer" : "c2", "date" : "d2" }, "percentage" : 79.16... }
```

Comment: Please post ur data set

Comment: Could you add sample documents and expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { "customer": "$customer", "date": "$date" },
            percentage: { $sum: { $add: [ "$time_moving", "$time_idling" ] } }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            percentage: {
                $divide: [ "$percentage", 864 ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

You can use `$sum` to get all `time_moving` and `time_idling` per group and then use `$divide` to divide that value by the number of seconds.

Comment: Hi @mickl 
I think he also wanted to perform `avg` operation on it.  I think you might need to add one more stage for doing `avg` operation. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @RahulRaj are right, this is doing sum(v1, d1, v2, d1)/864 where as I need avg(v1, d1, v2, d1)/864. Replacing $sum with $avg did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

https://mongoplayground.net/p/mhkW0LlTcI7

```
db={
  "orders": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "item": "almonds",
      "minCompTime": 10,
      "maxCompTime": 20,
      "minCompCost": 10,
      "maxCompCost": 20,
      "quantity": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": 4,
      "item": "pecans",
      "maxCompTime": 20,
      "maxCompCost": 20,
      "quantity": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": 3
    }
  ],
}

db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "avgCompTime": {
        "$avg": {
          "$divide": [
            {
              "$add": [
                {
                  "$ifNull": [
                    "$minCompTime",
                    "$maxCompTime"
                  ],
                  
                },
                {
                  "$ifNull": [
                    "$maxCompTime",
                    "$minCompTime"
                  ],
                  
                },
                
              ]
            },
            2
          ]
        }
      },
      "avgCompCost": {
        "$avg": {
          "$divide": [
            {
              "$add": [
                {
                  "$ifNull": [
                    "$minCompCost",
                    "$maxCompCost"
                  ],
                  
                },
                {
                  "$ifNull": [
                    "$maxCompCost",
                    "$minCompCost"
                  ],
                  
                },
                
              ]
            },
            2
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```